# Incorrect back button response

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

**Reproduction steps**:

1. view feed
2. view inbox
3. click inbox item question link
4. click back button

**Expected results**: I'd expect to go back to my feed.

**Actual results**: I end up on the current question's main site.

If I click an achievement link then the back button takes me back to my feed as I'd expect.

(Using 1.0.1.86)

Comment: Reproduced. Wonder if it's new to version 86 or always happened...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inbox behavior should now match that of achievements. This behavior will appear in the next Appstore update, and in the Beta for version 1.0.1.87.